# C# : convert an integer value into datetime(mmm-yyyy)

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

convert an integer value into datetime(mmm-yyyy)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I got my answer.

```
string dtName = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(6) + " - " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
```